# How to extract latitude and longitude values from the object of the class "google.maps.LatLng"?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
directionsService.route (request, 
                            function (result, status) 
                            {
                                alert(status);
                                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
                                {
                                    directionsDisplay.setDirections (result);

                                    pointsArray = result.routes[0].overview_path;
```

The problem is that the ***result.routes[0].overview_path;*** returns an array of type **'google.maps.LatLng'**. i.e. Each element is an "object" of the class 'google.maps.LatLng', in that array.

I want to write all those returned latitudes and longitudes on a text file.

How to extract the individual "latitudes and longitudes" values from the object of the class "**google.maps.LatLng**"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng

The above link contains two methods: `lat()` and `lng()` which do solve the issue.
The code for the same is as follows:

```
function displayRoute ()
    {
        var start = arrayMarkers [0];
        var end   = arrayMarkers [1];

        var request = {
                    origin:start,
                    destination:end,
                    travelMode:google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
                    };

        directionsService.route (request, function (result, status) 
        {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
            {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections (result);
                pointsArray = result.routes[0].overview_path;

                var i = 0;
                var j = 0;

                for (j = 0; j < pointsArray.length; j++)
                {
                    arrayToBeReturned [i] = pointsArray[j].lat ();
                    i++;
                    arrayToBeReturned [i] = pointsArray[j].lng ();
                    i++;

                    var point1 = new google.maps.Marker ({
                                                    position:pointsArray [j],
                                                    draggable:false,
                                                    map:map,
                                                    flat:true
                                                    });
                }
            }
        });
   }
```

Comment: I needed the same thing and did exactly that. Thanks.